# Regex that matches a word bound by start and end of a string or non-word characters

Tags: python, regex, perl

My first attempt is:

```
[\A\b]+(word)[\Z\b]+
```

But for some reason it is not working.
Im using Python/Perl regexes.

The regex should capture a word in such strings:

```
,word
word,
,word,
word
```

Comment: please add some context.. for your examples using ``(\w+)`` would give you ``word``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero-width anchors like `\A` and `\b` cannot be used inside character classes, nor can you have more than one of them adjacent to each other, so the `+` is meaningless.

However, `\b` will already match a boundary at the start or end of the string, so this should work:

```
\b(word)\b
```

[**Demonstration**](http://fiddle.re/63mj9)