# what can i do to find the sentence that only contains 'take'?

Tags: python

I want to find all the sentences with the word 'take' in this list (x), but one of the outputs is 'Own your mis**take**s before the Council'. What can I do if I only want the sentence containing 'take' instead of some words that have take inside them?

This is my code:

```
x =['Own your mistakes before the Council,', "You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?", "Maybe just don't take Powder next time.", "You don't understand what's at stake.", 'You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,', '- Did they take anything dangerous?', 'Do whatever it takes.', "I'll take the strongest shit you got."]
```

```
for i in x:
    if 'take'in i:
        print(i)
```

Comment: how about `[s for s in x if ' take' in s]`

Comment: See regex solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943773/regex-that-matches-a-word-bound-by-start-and-end-of-a-string-or-non-word-charact). Not exactly dupe, but very similar. In python you can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) standard module to work with regular expressions.

Comment: @enke it doesn't filter out sentences with word `"mistakes"`, the question is clearly about that.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It does though. Notice the leading white space.

Comment: Ough, sorry, missed that in inline code. But `takeaway` will kill this too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add spaces around "take", so " take ", or spilt the lines and  check if it contains "take". As explained by @SUTerliakov, my first suggestion won't work all the time.

This is what the code might look like for my second suggestion.

```
sentences =['Own your mistakes before the Council,', "You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?", "Maybe just don't take Powder next time.", "You don't understand what's at stake.", 'You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,', '- Did they take anything dangerous?', 'Do whatever it takes.', "I'll take the strongest shit you got."]

for sentence in sentences:
    words = sentence.lower().split()
    if "take" in words:
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: It's almost great, and will work for some cases. However, when you'll want to find both `take` and `Take` (ignore capitalization) or lowercase the sentences for the same reason, you'll miss sentences like `"take this cake, please"` since there's no space at the beginning. With some preprocessing (append and prepend space to each string) it will work almost always, but may be inefficient to query only once. Upvoted, but it will be great to add this discussion to the answer (and some code to be more visual, maybe).

Comment: Oh, nice observation. I will add your suggestion to my suggestion.

Comment: UPD: and sentence end may be troublesome, too, even without lowercasing (`Let's take`).

Comment: God, I haven't thought initially that it would be *this* hard without regex. Now your code fails with punctuation: `Do it, take, and see what happened`, rare - but not impossible.

Comment: @SUTerliakov That's true, I'll fail to catch the sentence that starts with 'take' if I add the space in the front. ahhh

Comment: Probably `words = sentence.lower().replace(',', '').replace('.', '').replace('!', '')...[other punctuation symbols here].split()` will work (`replace` can be done in a loop, or with `re.sub` - but the point is not to use `re`!).

Comment: oh, I think the new version of Aryan Arora's answer will do it too, thank you so much!!! you guys are amazing!!

Comment: You can use regex to make it even better. You should lowercase the string and use this `"\btake\b"` in your regex. It should cover all the cases. Fingers crossed. (Just noticed someone else posted it)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this discussion complete, this solution will hopefully catch all `take` occurrences ignoring case:

```py
import re
# Can use one-liner, but cached will work faster in a loop
regex = re.compile(r'\btake\b')
sentences = [
    'Own your mistakes before the Council,', 
    "You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?",
    "Maybe just don't take Powder next time.",
    "You don't understand what's at stake.",
    'You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,',
    '- Did they take anything dangerous?',
    'Do whatever it takes.',
    "I'll take the strongest shit you got.",
    'Take this!',
]
for sentence in sentences:
    if regex.search(sentence.lower()):  # Remove .lower() to be case-sensitive
        print(sentence)
```

Will print

```
You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?
Maybe just don't take Powder next time.
You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,
- Did they take anything dangerous?
I'll take the strongest shit you got.
Take this!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# cat take.py
sentences = [
    'Own your mistakes before the Council,', 
    "You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?",
    "Maybe just don't take Powder next time.",
    "You don't understand what's at stake.",
    'You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,',
    '- Did they take anything dangerous?',
    'Do whatever it takes.',
    "I'll take the strongest shit you got.",
    'Take this!',
]

istake = False
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence.lower().split():
        if word == "take":
             istake = True
             break
    if istake == True:
        print sentence
        istake = False
```

Sample Output

```
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# python take.py 
You guys know I wouldn't take you on a job you couldn't handle, right?
Maybe just don't take Powder next time.
You may take your son home, Mrs. Talis,
- Did they take anything dangerous?
I'll take the strongest shit you got.
Take this!
[root@cscale-82-69 python]#
```